# checkedlistbox in C#, display only file name, not full path

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

[I am trying to select a bunch of files and put the names into a checkedlistbox but it always displays the full directory path with the filename.  I only want the user to see the file name but I want to preserve the path inside the code so when the user clicks a button the program can still find the files and operate on them.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20e059c7-2604-41ae-8f9f-1480038ae3e2/listbox-in-c-net-20-display-only-file-name-not-full-path?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

My question has already been asked on another forum but I can't seem to get the expected results, currently, my code does as follows:

1. user clicks button_1: User selects folder containing files
2. all CSV files with only their file name in the checkedlistbox are displayed, with a message box appearing displaying their full paths. The user proceeds to check necessary files.
3. User clicks button_2: Displays a message box with the checked filenames, but not the full file paths, of which I am trying to retrieve.

Any help in this would be most appreciated thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace SelectFiles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                List<FileInfo> excel_files = new List<FileInfo>();

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
                    MessageBox.Show((f.FullName));
                    excel_files.Add(f);
                }
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = excel_files;
                checkedListBox1.DataSource = bs;
                checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";//Path.GetFileName(file);
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<FileInfo> list_all_excelfiles = new List<FileInfo>();
            foreach (FileInfo item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                list_all_excelfiles.Add(item);
                MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(item.FullName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't call `checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();` when the datasource property is set, can you? Is this the actual code that you're running?

Comment: If you want just the file name displayed use f.Name

Comment: It is just a bug in the MessageBox.Show() call, you don't like Path.GetFileName().  Don't use MessageBox to debug your code, use the debugger.  Practice using breakpoints and watch expressions.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by a bug in `MessageBox.Show()` ?

Comment: Use MessageBox.Show(item.FullName) instead.

Comment: @RufusL this is the code that I'm running and haven't experienced any errors due to that line of code.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know what breakpoints and expressions are I will look them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the **file full path** when user click on button2.

This can be achieved by modifying your code.

In the button2 event, are asking for `Path.GetFileName`

Change it to

```
Path.GetFullPath
```

> which will return the full path of the file.

Your code should be looks like :

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<FileInfo> list_all_excelfiles = new List<FileInfo>();
  foreach (FileInfo item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
       list_all_excelfiles.Add(item);
       MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFullPath(item.Name));
    }
}
```

**Note** : in your code, you are trying to clear the items from checkedListBox1 by `Clear()` method but you'll face an exception.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when
>   the DataSource property is set.'

and that's because you added a data source already !

instead use :

```
checkedListBox1.DataSource = null;
```

Comment: Thanks that works! I will do what you say and change checkedListBox1.DataSource = null;     although I haven't faced any problems using the code as is.

Comment: You are welcome, you'll face the problem if you add a folder, than try to add another folder. So to be in the safe side, change it :) and don't forget to accept the answer if it helps :)